# Cascade MacPorts 'select' commands?

Tags: python, macports

I've got different ports of python installed - for example, python26, python27, python27-apple.

I've also got different python modules installed - for example, py26-kerberos and py27-kerberos.

How can I "cascade" the "port select --set  " commands so that when I select python26, the py26-* installed ports are also selected?

(Obviously, I could script this myself. But this seems like such an obvious thing to do that I'm sure I've simply missed some crucial piece of documentation somewhere...)

Comment: Are you sure you need to do this? I believe there is no need for selecting between `py26-kerberos` and `py27-kerberos`; they coexist with no conflicts, installed into separate site-packages (`/opt/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages` and `/opt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`). If they install any scripts in your PATH, they should be named `fooscript-2.6`, and have a shbang line pointing to `/opt/local/bin/python2.6` rather than `/usr/bin/env python`. (This isn't even a MacPorts thing, it's how Python works by default on all *nix systems.)

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid. If there is a fooscript-2.6 and a fooscript-2.7, and there is a fooscript_select port, I want the python select to also cascade the various fooscript_select's so that I can just run "fooscript" instead of having to run fooscript-2.$whatever

Comment: Well, the vast majority of Python modules _don't_ have such scripts, but I guess there are a few that do (`ipython`, `pycolor`, …). Do you actually have enough that this is a problem? Or does MacPorts force you to select even for the ones that don't conflict at all, meaning you're pretty much guaranteed the problem? (Sorry if I'm asking stupid questions; I stopped using MacPorts a few years ago, and even when I used it, I used `setuptools` to manage my Python packages, not ports…)

Comment: As far as I can tell, port does have relationship data - there is a dependency link in the port file that will cause the install to fetch and install the depended port. I don't see any cascade option documented, and when I select python26, I still pyflakes33, for example.